# URL - linebreak and page break

Tags: urls

I'm using luatatex 1.0.4 and I already found some solutions for breaking urls. Nevertheless I have special cases for which I didn't find a solution. My sample code looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-\do\_\do\%} % for breaking long URLS additonally
\begin{document}

\href{http://google.com}{http://www.darinews.com/\%D8\%A7\%D8\%B2-\%D8\%B3\%D8\%B1\%DA\%AF\%DB\%8C\%D8\%B1\%DB\%8C-\%D9\%BE\%D8\%B1\%D9\%88\%D8\%A7\%D8\%B2-\%D9\%87\%D8\%A7\%DB\%8C-\%D8\%AE\%D8\%A7\%D8\%B1\%D8\%AC\%DB\%8C-\%D8\%A7\%D8\%B2-\%D9\%85\%DB\%8C\%D8\%AF\%D8\%A7\%D9\%86-\%D8\%A8\%DB\%8C\%D9\%86-\%D8\%A7/}

\end{document}
```

I'm aware that the sample looks somehow weird nevertheless its a good one.

I have the list of links  collected in each sections - just as a regular text. They are `itemize`. Since the lists are quite long it can happen that an url is broken into two lines just when the page break occurs. As a consequnce the page number and the page header of the next page are clickable from the link. How to disable this behaviour?
[image]

Comment: Don't put to many questions in one question. Split them up. And add example for every problem.

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is your issue solved? How?

Comment: I don't know what kind of news you are looking for. I split up my original q. The problem with the clickable area still persists although it is not a pressing one.  Especially since it is not happening that often. If there exists an idea how combine page break and hrefs without introducing additionally inconsistency in the clicking areas I would appreciate.