# bibtex entry too long so URL gets split on 2 pages

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, page-breaking

> Possible duplicate [How can I prevent page break between lines of a
>   paragraph or bibliography entry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28/140133)

I have some bibliography entries and one of them gets split on 2 pages.
exaclty as posted in the following thread, but unfortunatly there was no answer.
[same problem but unanswered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470496/url-linebreak-and-page-break?rq=1)

maybe someone can help me out by explaining how to force the whole respective entry on the next page or extend the page by 1 or 2 lines. Or other solutions.

tried using package `xurl`- no results
tried

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}
\enlargethispage{1\baselineskip}
\bibliography{meinebib}
```

didn't do what I hoped for

Cheers

Comment: Hi @CRoNiC and Welcome to TeX-SE. Are you using the same MWE as the other thread? Have you tried the package `xurl`? I *think* it might solve. I remember using it for line breaks but don't remember exactly how is the behavior or how other packages or bibliographystyles might interfere.

Comment: If the offending entry is on the first page of the bibliography, you could try inserting this command before the bibliography: `\enlargethispage{1\baselineskip}`.  (This should be done only on the final run.)

Comment: @FHZ i tried using `xurl` but nothing seems to change.

Comment: @barbarabeeton tried your suggestion aswell, but nothing happened too. see edit

Comment: If there are exactly two lines of the bib entry left on the second page, trying to enlarge the first page by `1\baselineskip` might be foiled by a prohibition against leaving widow lines, so instead using `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}` might have a better chance.  Or *decrease* the length of the first page by 1 line (or 2, if you have a situation where the bib entry is exactly 4 lines long).  If you could show the troublesome entry as typeset (but as a unit, not split), we wouldn't be so dependent on our crystal ball.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, as I'm quite new in this forum, would CRoNiC's question be considered a duplicate? (From the link I put in my answer). I don't know exactly how to proceed to edit the question, nor if I have the privilege.

Comment: @FHZ -- Looking at the question you linked in your answer, yes, that does appear to be a reasonable near duplicate, and can be proposed as such.  (See also my comment following your answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before answering, I would like to point out a very important thing.
When asking questions, please inform us a MWE. It helps a lot to know your problem and avoids misinterpretations.

That said, I will **assume** your problem *is not* url splitting into 2 pages, *but* actually *any* bibliography text splitting into 2 pages.

For this question, there was an answer: [How can I prevent page break between lines of a paragraph or bibliography entry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28/how-can-i-prevent-page-break-between-lines-of-a-paragraph-or-bibliography-entry)

The simplest method is to insert `\interlinepenalty=10000` in your preamble. ***Edit Note***: It will change the behavior of the whole text. Explanations below.

From the link: "You can modify the variable that tells TeX how bad an idea it is to break up lines of a paragraph". Check the link for a full explanation.

OBS: When you asked about the link, I really thought the issue came from large links going beyond the page or similarly. Sorry for that.

Please, test this option in your text.

Figures to illustrate follow.

Without `\interlinepenalty=10000`.

[image]

With `\interlinepenalty=10000`.

[image]

**Edit**: Following barbaras comment.

With `\interlinepenalty=10000` at preamble you will break paragraphs you probably don't want.

[image]

With `\interlinepenalty=10000` just before `bibliography` only References will break as desired. Other paragraphs will break normally.

[image]

A MWE (with my external `.bib` files, sorry for that) follows.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}

% ============ Here, all paragraphs will not break
%\interlinepenalty=10000

\begin{document}

\cite{Meza_Zucatelli_Interface_2016}, \cite{Zucatelli_Meza_Fenili_LagranTexPack}.

\lipsum[1-14]. % 13 14

A.

B.

%C.
%
%D.

% ============ Here, only paragraphs in bibliography will not break
\interlinepenalty=10000

% Use your external .bib file.
\bibliography{C:/Users/FHZ/Dropbox/Artigos_Publicados_pdf_bib/Artigo_Meza_Zucatelli_IJCSSE_Bibtex,C:/Users/FHZ/Dropbox/Artigos_Publicados_pdf_bib/Artigo_Zucatelli_Meza_Fenili_LagranTexPack_IJCTE_Bibtex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\interlinepenalty=10000` would indeed take care of this; good for you for finding the linked question.  But in this case, placing that command in the preamble may be too severe.  Depending on the nature of the document, particularly if it contains long paragraphs, it could be counterproductive to prohibit all paragraphs from being broken at a page break.  Placing the `\interlinepenalty=10000` just before the bibliography would restrict the action to that section.

Comment: Thanks kindly for the comment. I really forgot to check how the command interferes with the rest of the text. I edited to include a brief example of your comment.